# SP2013 Multiple Membership Providers for multiple applications on same farm

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication, security-token-service, membership-provider

I have two web applications in my farm. for each application i have configured a separate SQL Membership Provider.

each provider is defined in:

Central Admin

STS

and the related Web Application

both providers have exactly the same settings only differ in name and connection string. and all are configured in the web.config files using a powershell script

the issue is that one of them works fine the other is giving (Cannot Get Membership Provider with name . the membership provider is not properly configured).

when I deployed this to my test farm. the issue occurred but for different Application. the one working in development is not working in test and the one not working in development is now working in test.

it seems like a random behavior but I cannot find out what the root cause.

hope to find some help from you

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some issues in your web.config files. Please make sure your Web application entries for membership and role provider(at central admin site) are matching with Web.config entries. your error "**Cannot get Membership Provider with name CustomRoleProvider.** ", indicating that you may have used role provider name in Membership provider text box or in web.config.

Also please make sure that you have correct entries in all 3 web.config files - Central Administration , Security Token Service (STS), Web application .

Also see you might not have the Claims to Windows Token Service started which is located in Central Administration > Manage Services On Server. Once u turned that on, it might started working. Please check and revert me if you need more assistance.

Comment: fortunately the issue is solved when I deleted the two applications and re-created them with same scripts again. i still do not know what was the issue. because web.config files are updated using powershell script not manual update.